# Suspiciously low CTR for brand searches reported by Google search console

Tags: google-search-console, reporting, clicks

I have a client who is ranking 1, 2, and 3 for their brand name but has 0% CTR according to Google search console.

There are no PPC ads running on these search queries.

Can the GSC data for CTR be inaccurate or is this a reporting bug? The CTR has been 0% for months but other keywords are reporting expected CTR percents (Rank 1 25% CTR, etc)

Comment: Many things effect CTR. It could be that people who are searching for your target terms are not searching for what you are offering. If they are, then you may not be compelling enough to have your SERP link clicked upon. It is like guessing what ferrets want on T.V. Nearly impossible. Instead, I recommend focusing not on targeted keywords which are subject to being completely wrong, but rather how your site is actually found organically and increasing performance there. This is one case where betting on the winners is a good thing.

Comment: If someone searched for "Red ties" and the first 3 results were "red ties" and the next 7 results were "black cars" I think it's safe to assume that the intent of the search for "Red ties" was to find one of the first 3 results over the next 7, correct?

Comment: If search was that simple. Sometimes it is. I was just throwing out the usual points to consider. Not knowing what you are targeting, it is impossible for anyone to know. I know that some search impressions never result in a click. That is just the way it is. Consider the SERP link and snippet. It may not be matching user expectations somehow even though you and I might think it is excellent. That is why we experiment. I am on your side. Honest! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Webmaster Tools, you can look at two numbers.

1. The impressions for the branded keywords. If its not being search enough number of times, even if you might be ranking 1, 2 and 3 for those terms, the CTR would be 0% (since its not being searched at all).
2. The snippet showing up on each of these listings when you do a brand keyword search. Are there glaring issues that might be turning off people from the brand search.

Another factor to consider could be how unique the brand term is. If the brand term is generic ("cool jeans", "metropolis labs", etc) then there might be a different meaning for folks who are searching the brand term.